# What type of hash is this?

Tags: hash

I am not very good at this and have searched high and low to try and motivate if this is a good or bad hash. I hope that one of you could enlighten me with some information regarding this.

```
unsigned int hash(bytearray[] msg) 
{ 
  unsigned int hash = 0xDECAFBAD; 
  for(i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) 
  { 
     hash = ((hash << 5) XOR (hash >> 27)) XOR msg[i]; 
  } 
  return (hash BITWISE-AND 0x7FFFFFFF); 
}
```

Comment: What's your definition of "good/bad"? What requirements are you trying to meet with this algorithm?

Comment: I do not have any real requirements. Just a general feeling how well written this is.

Comment: But what's it for? Hash tables? Cryptographic hashes? "How good is this" is a subjective question that's hard to answer, "Is this first preimage, second preimage, and collision resistant?" is a little more quantifiable.

Comment: cryptohraphic hashes, my bad :)